# Can I talk to allah in my head?

Tags: dua

If I have  worries can I tell Allah? ALso is there a reason your dua should be a secret and u should not tell people, Like im worried about this thing which I am not going to say can I talk to allah about through dua or mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allah [swt] said in his holy book

> ...Allah knows whatever lies in your hearts, and Allah is All-Knowing, All-Wise.

Quran 33:51

So Allah [swt] knows everything and hears you have ever you make the Duaa inshallah.

And i dont know about anything saying not to tell others about your Duaa.

Other then that when making duaa you dont say "oh good if you want" or "oh good if you please" you just go directly into the subject like "oh Allah please give me so and so" and then it is better that before the Duaa you start by praising Allah [swt] and making salat on the prophet [pbuh] then saying your duaa and then ending it with a salat on the prophet and prising allah twords the end.

Comment: It just i thought my dua is between me and allah

Comment: You'r duaa is between you and Allah [swt] and that is why when the prophet was missing makkeh and when our qibla was jersulem Allah [swt] said "We have certainly seen the turning of your face, [O Muhammad], toward the heaven, and We will surely turn you to a qiblah with which you will be pleased. So turn your face toward al-Masjid al-Haram" Quran 2:144. So the prophet [pbuh] didn't even need to make a Duaa, Allah [swt] just feelt his servant not being happy and he replied.